# Wagtail streamtext paragraph unedtiable in demo blog causing django app to crash

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am attempting to follow the demo blog project, to get up to speed with wagtail. I've installed wagtail into an existing django app.

http://wagtail-nesting-box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_blog/

I installed nesting box:

```
pip install wagtail-nesting-box
```

I added the following into my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'wagtail_box',
    'wagtail_box.blog',
    'wagtail.contrib.settings',
]
```

I migrated the changes within my virtualenv using:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I created a blog page as per the instructions, then a child item blog post.

The blog post editor loads, and I see the various fields, including the body... However when I click the paragraph element , a blue box appears, but I am unable to edit it.

If I click the H2 element, I can edit this. But the Paragraph element, is locked and I can not add any text to it.

If I attempt to save the page with nothing in the paragraph element I receive the following error:

```
ValueError at /cms/pages/7/edit/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Which i've traced back to this code, in stream_block.py

```
 int(data['%s-%d-order' % (prefix, i)]),
```

How can I unlock the paragraph element so that it's editable?

How can I generate a more user friendly error? So the django app doesn't crash if it has an empty paragraph field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is Javascript that makes certain regions editable, that needs to be placed in your static folder.

Locate each of the following folders: -

```
wagtailadmin
wagtaildocs
wagtailembeds
wagtailimages
wagtailsnippets
wagtailusers
```

Each of these folders, contains a static directory.
Copy the contents of each static directory, into your public web static folder.

It's specifically the wagtailembeds static javascript that makes the body editable.